# What is the best practice to map client (not user) objectives/needs?

Tags: personas, users

I am working on developing an updated interface to a pre-existing set of services in the form of a web app. We have a limited number of clients (20ish) about 170ish users. I've been interviewing clients and finding while they use our services they have very different objectives and needs. Originally I was going to develop personas for users but I think these may be driven by the objectives of the organization they work for.

I'm new to personas.

- Is there a best practice I can use to map the hierarchal needs and objectives of an organization?
- Is there a way these are incorporated into part of a persona?

Answer (score 3):

Because examples communicate better than abstractions, here's an [affinity diagram](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592537561).

- Organizing my information

  - show me what I have to do

    - daily to-do lists help me track progress

      - U3 302 likes the prioritization format in her day planner
      - U5 518 makes a report for group with day's hot tasks every day
      - U138 checks things off her to-do list as she finishes them
    - I want it printed in front of me

      - U2 221 prints calendar several times a day and hangs them next to her computer
      - U7 743 transfers meetings from email to wall calendar
      - U3 351 likes getting an email with tasks rather than a phone call so she can print it
    - don't interrupt me with non-critical stuff

      - U5 523 has his email set so only urgent mail is automatically opened
      - U1 12 keeps her inbox behind her so she won't be interrupted

Here's what each post it note represents

- Overarching area of concern

  - specific issues within area of concern

    - aspects of an issue revealed by customer (in this example it's 3 columns)

      - single observation, insight, concern or requirement firmly rooted in research data

Make groups of these on a wall to get a [big picture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558604111) of your interview data. Good luck!